# Asynchronous Loading of images in gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtkmm

Currently, in my project, we are using gtkmm pixbuf **create_from_file** or **create_from_date** which hangs up whole GUI for 1-2 seconds in case of high-resolution images and in case of loading multiple images for a screen it becomes awfully slow. Is it possible to load images asynchronously in gtkmm for the above two functions? I am able to find methods in gtk for loading images asynchronously but not in gtkmm. An example would be helpful since I am unable to find anything related to it.

```
  if(!imageName.empty())
  {
    //Load image in pixbuf
    picPixBuff = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file(imageName);

    picPixBuff = picPixBuff->scale_simple(150,35,Gdk::INTERP_BILINEAR);

   }
```

I have gone through this.
**Related Question** - [How to load a widget as a different thread in gtk? (vala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831889/how-to-load-a-widget-as-a-different-thread-in-gtk-vala)

Comment: Tried to have a crack at this, but I'm not going to post my half baked answer as I'm missing a lot of gtkmm skills. What I was going to elaborate was that there is not an asynchronous equivalent in gtkmm for your function, so you'll have to write one yourself. Basically write a function that loads your buffer and signals some other function afterwards, which then uses it. Then call this function in its own thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-multithread-example.html.en) for that. That example does exactly what you are asking for.

These are the functions that do the magic. The example is easy to follow.

```
// notify() is called from ExampleWorker::do_work(). It is executed in the worker
// thread. It triggers a call to on_notification_from_worker_thread(), which is
// executed in the GUI thread.
void ExampleWindow::notify()
{
  m_Dispatcher.emit();
}

void ExampleWindow::on_notification_from_worker_thread()
{
  if (m_WorkerThread && m_Worker.has_stopped())
  {
    // Work is done.
    if (m_WorkerThread->joinable())
      m_WorkerThread->join();
    delete m_WorkerThread;
    m_WorkerThread = nullptr;
    update_start_stop_buttons();
  }
  update_widgets();
}
```

Comment: So this is would be applicable for pixbuf also right? Like in thread function we will create pixbuf from file and on notify we just render on screen.

Comment: @Freedom911 That's the idea. You do what you can do independently of the GUI in the worker thread and update the GUI in the GUI thread (so you avoid concurrent problems) as noted in the three first comment lines.